# In the Download folder, What ~$ mean?

Tags: macos, command-line, filesystem

In the Download folder, when I do ls, I can find this

```
El lobo solitario y su cachorro (Kazuo Koike y Goseki Kojima) - Tomo 01.cbr ~$OL 68412 Advanced Clinical Bioinformatics 2022 Timetable.docx
~$007007 annonomised report(1) (1).doc                      ~$tcome Letter to Employee[6].docx
~$Low_Throughput_Panels_Transcripts_v5_DRAFT.xlsm               ~$v Clin Bio Assignments 2021 (2).docx
```

What ~$ mean? These files are not in the folder when I open it. Mac 12.5.1 (21G83)

Comment: It looks to be part of the filename. Try the command `ls -il` and post the output

Answer (score 1):

Those are valid file names. On macOS you should be able to get more information on the file (from where it was downloaded / metadata like modified date and time / alternate names / localized names) in the get info window, using a third party app to show the metadata or the `mdls` command.

As mentioned in the comments - getting a long listing would help wrap the lines and present one file per line if you are not seeing line wraps in your output (we don't see them correctly in the first version of your question).

```
ls -li ~/Downloads
mdls ~/Downloads/~$Low_Throughput_Panels_Transcripts_v5_DRAFT.xlsm
```

My hunch is that they are not named that but that your web browser or another program doing the downloads is naming them, but it could be exactly how they were named before you downloaded and this is just the correct behavior.

Look at the display name, FS name and kMDItemWhereFroms parts of the `mdls` output for the files if they don't appear as relevant to this answer and your situation.